# How to disable the OS selection screen?

Tags: raspbian, boot, noobs

I have installed Raspbian via NOOBS.
So this is the one and only OS in my SD card.
But I always found myself at the OS selection screen every boot, and I have to wait 10 second to boot to Raspbian.

Is there a way to turn off this OS selection screen?

Is it enough to delete `/boot/os_config.json`?

EDIT:

My boot screen shows only one entry.

`/boot/os_config.json` file contains:

```
[
  {
    "bootable": true,
    "description": "A port of Debian jessie for the Raspberry Pi (full desktop version)",
    "folder": "/settings/os/Raspbian",
    "icon": "/settings/os/Raspbian/icon.png",
    "name": "Raspbian",
    "partitions": [
      "/dev/mmcblk0p6",
      "/dev/mmcblk0p7"
    ],
    "release_date": "2017-07-05",
    "supported_models": [
      "Pi Model",
      "Pi 2",
      "Pi Zero",
      "Pi 3"
    ]
  }
]
```

`sudo cfdisk /dev/mmcblk0` shows:

```
Free space              2048     8191     6144    3M                 
/dev/mmcblk0p1          8192   137215   129024   63M  e W95 FAT16 (LB
/dev/mmcblk0p2        137216 31116287 30979072 14.8G  5 Extended
├─/dev/mmcblk0p5      139264   204797    65534   32M 83 Linux
├─/dev/mmcblk0p6      204800   339967   135168   66M  c W95 FAT32 (LB
├─Free space          342016   344064     2049    1M                 
└─/dev/mmcblk0p7      344064 31116287 30772224 14.7G 83 Linux
```

Comment: The `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is the `NOOBS` selection screen and `/dev/mmcblk0p6` is your Linux boot partition. You can replace `/dev/mmcblk0p1` with `/dev/mmcblk0p6` and that would boot up faster. There would not be any recovery if anything went wrong. I would suggest to get another sd card for backup or to only install Raspbian on it. To replace  NOOBS boot with Raspbian boot, my thoughts would be, `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt`, `sudo rm -R /mnt/*`, `sudo rsync -axv /boot/ /mnt/`, `ls -l /mnt`, and `ls -l /boot`, they should be the same (not actually tested).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Libreelec: only one OS available and NOOBS asked everytime which one to boot (with a list of 1 element of course).

In my case I solved by going in the configuration by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> during boot, then I **unchecked and then re-checked** Libreelec in the list and finally exit with <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

The subsequent boots went to Libreelec without the OS selection to popup.

Answer (score 1):

Set `bootmenutimeout=n` on `/boot/cmdline.txt` to change the setting to `n` seconds. Minimum allowed is `1`.

You cannot skip the boot screen unless there is only one OS installed, if you want to use only one OS, you can install this one from scratch, or you can try to remove the others.

As you can see on your `sudo cfdisk /dev/mmcblk0` result, you have two partition with Linux, I think you have to remove partitions that are not listed on `/boot/os_config.json`

Comment: But the problem is that I only have ONE OS installed but the boot screen still appears

Comment: Can you check this file? `/media/pi/SETTINGS/installed_os.jso`

You see the OS selection screen with only one choice?

Comment: `[
 {
  "bootable" : true,
  "description" : "A port of Debian jessie for the Raspberry Pi (full desktop version)",
  "folder" : "/settings/os/Raspbian",
  "icon" : "/settings/os/Raspbian/icon.png",
  "name" : "Raspbian",
  "partitions" : [
"/dev/mmcblk0p6",
"/dev/mmcblk0p7"
  ],
  "release_date" : "2017-07-05",
  "supported_models" : [
"Pi Model",
"Pi 2",
"Pi Zero",
"Pi 3"
  ]
 }
]`

Comment: Please add this on your question, not in comment, also try to run `sudo cfdisk /dev/mmcblk0` and insert in your question the result, it will show you partitions on SD

Comment: I like this answer.  It simply keeps that selection screen up for only 1 second.  However, with NOOBS I have never had it show this screen after the install.  If this is a new machine you might want to run through NOOBS again.